# Emacs: override major mode key-map with general

Tags: emacs, package

I have a list of keybindings that I want to use in all modes. However, in the simplified example below, I get the error `Error (use-package): general/:config: Key sequence SPC x starts with non-prefix key SPC`.

```
(use-package paradox
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :config
  (setq paradox-spinner-type 'progress-bar)
  paradox-execute-asynchronously t))

(defun add-general-bindings ()
  (general-define-key
   :states '(normal visual insert emacs motion)
   :prefix "SPC"
   :non-normal-prefix "C-SPC"
   "x"   'counsel-M-x
   "SPC" 'avy-goto-char-2
   "/"   'swiper))

(add-hook 'paradox-menu-mode-hook 'add-general-bindings)
```

I though it might be because I did not unbind `SPC` for the paradox-menu-mode, but if adding

```
(general-unbind
  :states '(normal visual emacs motion)
  "SPC")
```

to the top of `add-general-bindings` the error still persists. is this the wrong approach to override keybindings of a major mode with the general package?

Comment: you can use `define-prefix-command` to create a prefix key with an associated map. What about a global minor-mode?

Comment: I will try that. I have read about the approach using a global minor mode but I liked the approach with the hook more (I know that's subjective). A follow up question: the approach above works if I remove the `:states` from the function `add-general-keybindings`. I do not understand why because paradox-menu-mode is in emacs state.

Comment: can't help you there, I dont use `use-package`. But, all modes you create, like a global minor-mode using `define-derived-mode` or the like will have hooks. You can also just create your own hooks, which are just variables, and use `run-hooks` or the other similar functions. The `define-...mode` macros create the hooks for you.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds very good. I will read into it and try that approach.